# getting error while post data in https url

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Post data to `url` and get `json` return. this was working fine with `http` but when i switch my website `http` to `https` code show error error occurred.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String nextUrl = "https://megsta.com/h/gettokenapi.php";
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailstr));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", passstr));

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(nextUrl, ServiceHandler.POST, params);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {

                status = jsonStr;
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post error details here

Comment: show error please

Comment: Just show error:  [ error occurred ] and nothing else

Comment: I tried to hit the url and received this response - {
"url": "https://b-api.facebook.com/restserver.php?api_key=3e7c78e35a76a9299309885393b02d97&email=emailstr&format=JSON&generate_session_cookies=1&locale=vi_vn&method=auth.login&password=saass&return_ssl_resources=1&v=1.0&sig=769bf7408b948ad77d9d9421782ea909"
}

try to print the jsonStr in logcat and check whether you are getting correct response or not.

Comment: okay but why this happen here i don't know

Comment: my service handler is http based 
 if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);